# Average between two datetime columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have the following query where I am trying to return the average between two `DateTime` columns.

My issue is it wants me to group by `SoftwarePackage1_VersionNumbers.EnvShortName`, which I don't want to do.

```
SELECT DBO.softwarepackage1_versionnumbers.envshortname                                                                                  AS [Environment Name],
       DBO.softwarepackage1_versionnumbers.currentversionnumber                                                                          AS [SoftwarePackage1 Current Version Number],
       DBO.softwarepackage1_versionnumbers.currentbuildname                                                                              AS [Current SoftwarePackage1 Build],
       DBO.softwarepackage1_versionnumbers.currentlastassociatedchangeset                                                                AS [Last Associated Changeset],
       DBO.softwarepackage1_versionnumbers.deploymentdate                                                                                AS [SoftwarePackage1 Deployment Date],
       DBO.softwarepackage2_versionnumbers.currentsoftwarepackage2displayedversionnumber                                                 AS [SoftwarePackage2ector Displayed Version Number],
       DBO.softwarepackage2_versionnumbers.currentsoftwarepackage2fullversionnumber                                                      AS [SoftwarePackage2ector Full Version Number],
       DBO.softwarepackage2_versionnumbers.currentlastfilewritedatetime                                                                  AS [SoftwarePackage2ector Last File Write Time],
       DBO.softwarepackage2_versionnumbers.deploymentdate                                                                                AS [SoftwarePackage2ector Deployment Date],
       Avg(Datediff(MINUTE, DBO.softwarepackage1_versionnumbers.modifieddatetime, DBO.softwarepackage2_versionnumbers.modifieddatetime)) AS [Last Version Check (UTC)]
FROM   DBO.softwarepackage1_versionnumbers
       FULL OUTER JOIN DBO.softwarepackage2_versionnumbers
                    ON DBO.softwarepackage1_versionnumbers.envid = DBO.softwarepackage2_versionnumbers.envid
       FULL OUTER JOIN DBO.systemenvironments
                    ON DBO.softwarepackage1_versionnumbers.envid = DBO.systemenvironments.envid
WHERE  ( DBO.softwarepackage1_versionnumbers.deleted = '0' )
       AND ( DBO.softwarepackage2_versionnumbers.deleted = 0 )
       AND ( DBO.systemenvironments.envtype = 'Development' )
```

Comment: Average for what range? Over all the rows in the resultset? Over a particular subrange?

Comment: It would be the average over the row

Comment: Did you get to try out my answer? Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar to one of the methods in this query:

```
SELECT name, create_date, modify_date, 
    CONVERT(DATETIME,(CONVERT(FLOAT,create_date)+CONVERT(FLOAT,modify_date))/2) AS AvgDate1,
    DATEADD(S,DATEDIFF(S,create_date,modify_date)/2.,create_date) AS AvgDate2
FROM sys.objects
```

Answer (score 0):

For the average over just two dates:

```
DECLARE @date2 DATETIME = GETDATE(), @date1 DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE());

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN @date1<@date2 
        THEN DATEADD(SECOND,DATEDIFF(SECOND,@date1,@date2)/2,@date1)
        ELSE DATEADD(SECOND,DATEDIFF(SECOND,@date2,@date1)/2,@date2)
    END;
```